# Heuristics for space-efficient storing of Unordered Finite Sets in a DFA

Tags: formal-languages, graphs, data-structures, finite-automata, data-compression

I've got an algorithm I'm working on that generates, stores, and iterates through a large number of finite sets. I'm finding that memory is a bottleneck long before time is.

The finite sets are subsets of the vertices $V$ in my graph, so each finite set is small, there's just a lot of them.

In an effort to save space, I've started representing the finite sets as binary words of length $|V|$, with a 0 indicating the element is not in the set, a 1 indicating that it is. I'm storing the collection of these words as an acyclic deterministic automaton (also known as DAWG, directed acyclic word graph).

However, this requires a fixed ordering of the potential elements, which is fine, but arbitrary. If a different ordering were more likely to produce a smaller output set, I'd be happy to use it.

I'm wondering:

- Is there a known, efficient algorithm for finding the permutation which gives the smallest DFA representing a set of finite sets?
- If not, has any research been done on heuristics for orderings which have been shown to often produce smaller DFAs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing a [binary decision diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram), also known as a BDD.  BDD's have been studied extensively in the literature, so you might take a look at the literature.

In particular, the question of finding the best permutation is known  as the "variable ordering" problem for BDDs.  Finding the optimal variable ordering is NP-hard.  There are some heuristics, but they don't always work.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram#Variable_ordering.  Probably the easiest approach is to use an existing BDD library (the standard ones will typically incorporate some variable ordering heuristics).

You might also be interested in [ZDDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-suppressed_decision_diagram).

Comment: Very interesting! Would it be safe to say that a Trie is a Binary Decision Tree where all paths leading to 0 are pruned, and a DAWG is a BDD where paths leading to 0 are pruned? Both of these assuming that our alphabet is binary? (I can see that with a larger alphabet, a Trie will be different from a BDT )

Comment: @jmite, that sounds entirely believable to me, but I'm not an expert and I haven't thought about it too carefully, so don't trust anything I have to say about it.  Yeah, I think BDDs assume the alphabet is binary.

Comment: Thus the B of BDD!